# Use pandas to sequentially evaluate strings on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, comparison

I have a large location dataset that has many input errors (telemarketing). I need to create a column that clearly identifies a State and that information maybe present in different columns.
The following toy data illustrates the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'State': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 
                             np.nan, 'California', np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Location': ['Seattle, Washington', 'California', 'INPUT ERROR', 'Portland, Oregon',
                              'INPUT ERROR', 'San Bernardino', 'ERROR', 'Seattle'],
                   'Origin': ['Portland, Oregon', 'San Francisco', 'RANDOM ERROR', 'INPUT ERROR',
                                   'Las Vegas, Nevada', 'Nevada, Barstow', 'Portland', 'Washington, Tacoma']})

states = ['Alaska', 'Arizona', 'California', 
          'Colorado', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 
          'Montana', 'Nevada', 'New Mexico', 
          'Oregon', 'Utah', 'Washington',
          'Wyoming']
```

I need to somehow fill the 'State' column with whichever value appears first (really does not matter!) from either the 'State' column or the 'Location' or 'Origin' columns. My thinking was to create a list of states and the compare each row and column to find a match and place the first match as the value in the 'State' column.

To achieve this i thought i would need to first split the strings in 'Location' and 'Origin' to single strings and then compare sequentially  (State>Location>Origin) till a valid state is found... got stuck there.

```
# Split string and create new columns for comparison
df[['Location1','Location2']] = df['Location'].str.split(', ', n=1, expand=True)
df[['origin1','origin2']] = df['Origin'].str.split(', ', n=1, expand=True)
```

Resulting in the following table[image: dataframe]

This is what i was trying:

```
# Go through each column one by one...
df.loc[df['Location2'].isin(states), 'State'] = df['Location2']
df.loc[df['origin1'].isin(states), 'State'] = df['origin1']
# Etc...
```

Notice that, in this case entry index 5 gets changed from California (Already in 'State' col) to Nevada (Valid State) as there is no sequence in the evaluation.

Summarizing i need to eval State, Location and Origin columns strings, sequentially to a valid state list, whichever first string is valid gets put in the 'State' column as the result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to extract a state using `pat` in `Location` then `Origin` columns. At each time, update nan values from `State` column with found states using `combine_first`.

```
pat = fr"({'|'.join(states)})"

df['State'] = \
    df['State'].combine_first(df['Location'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)) \
               .combine_first(df['Origin'].str.extract(pat, expand=False))
```

Regular expression find

```
>>> df
        State             Location              Origin
0  Washington  Seattle, Washington    Portland, Oregon
1  California           California       San Francisco
2         NaN          INPUT ERROR        RANDOM ERROR
3      Oregon     Portland, Oregon         INPUT ERROR
4      Nevada          INPUT ERROR   Las Vegas, Nevada
5  California       San Bernardino     Nevada, Barstow
6         NaN                ERROR            Portland
7  Washington              Seattle  Washington, Tacoma

>>> pat
'(Alaska|Arizona|California|Colorado|Hawaii|Idaho|Montana|Nevada|New Mexico|Oregon|Utah|Washington|Wyoming)'
```

Comment: I think you could use `functools.reduce` to avoid calling multiple times the same operation. (Might not be worth it for only two repeats, but would be important if there are many more columns) ;)

Comment: Anyway, +1 for the nice use of the not so well known `combine_first` :)

Comment: This works as intended, however i came across a slight issue on the real data. Sometimes the erroneous input is a substring of the pattern, which leads to wrong states being assigned. (for instance Mexico > New Mexico). Any ideas for exact matching?

Comment: Can you copy/paste  a such line please? 'New Mexico' should not match 'Mexico'

Comment: I tried to replace 'RANDOM ERROR' by 'Mexico' and the output State is NaN.

Comment: My bad, when passing on the solution actual dataframe i started getting the error **'Cannot align with a higher dimensional NDFrame'**, i tried to fix it by doing `df['State2'] = (df['Location'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)).iloc[:,0]` and going in turn and merging all in the end. This 'works' in the actual df (same structure, more rows) but in the example it throws out **IndexingError: Too many indexers**. Im baffled :\

Answer (score 1):

A quick any easy solution. Join all the fields, search for the first State name with a regex containing all States names:

```
pattern = '|'.join(states)
(df.fillna('')
    .apply(' '.join, axis=1)
    .str.findall(pattern)
    .str[0]
 )
```

Output:

```
0    Washington
1    California
2           NaN
3        Oregon
4        Nevada
5    California
6           NaN
7    Washington
```